# How to parse BigDecimal into Text with EU decimal separator but no decimal numbers at the end?

Tags: java, parsing, bigdecimal

I need to be able to be able to parse a `"1.000,"` string into a BigDecimal with value `1000`
and then parse that same BigDecimal back into a `"1.000,"` string.

Both should happen using the same exact `DecimalFormat` formatter.
Why? Because I need to compare at the end of each stage whether the two strings are equal, meaning whether the parsing was correct or not.

So far I tried to use these two patterns: `DecimalFormat("###.##0,")` and `DecimalFormat("0,")` but they don't produce the exact "1.000," at the end.

Here's my code:

```
List<NumberFormat> formats = new ArrayList<NumberFormat>();
formats.add(DecimalFormat("###.##0,"));
formats.add(DecimalFormat("0,"));

for(NumberFormat format : formats) {
 Number number = format.parse(text);
 format.setParseIntegerOnly(false);
 if (number != null && format(format, number).equals(text)) {
  return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: Surely `1.000,` can't be a valid number in any format.

Comment: The problem is that the format(format, number) call doesn't give me back "1.000," string for any of these formatters

Comment: This sounds like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you are really trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out.
I had to define the patterns as

`DecimalFormat("###,##0.", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN))`

and

`DecimalFormat("0.", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN))`

and I had to add this to the NumberFormat object:

```
format.setParseIntegerOnly(false);
```

to make it work for EU numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should consider using Regex for your problem.

You can replace , for . and add 000 at the end.

```
String str = "10,1";
str = str.replaceAll(",", ".");
System.out.println(str);
```

This will print "10.1"

EDIT:

```
String str = "1.000,";
str = str.replaceAll(",", "");
str = str.replaceAll(".", "");
int bigDecimal = Integer.valueOf(str);
//first part is done
System.out.println(str);
String regex = "(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+$)";
String result = bigDecimal.toString();
result = result.replaceAll(regex,".");
result = result + ",";
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: ow, maybe i don't understand the output expected. What is the right one?

Comment: The expected output is "1.000,"

Comment: I want to use DecimalFormat because I already have another 20 format defined that way so regex will not work for I'm trying to do.